# How to transform an image URL into a DOM file object using javascript/ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a script which allows me to crop images using jcrop.
To achieve that, I have to upload an image from my computer using the `input type file`. I want to extend the functionalities of my application, allowing the users to select photos from their facebook albuns, this code is working, but it returns me the URL of the image. 
From the URL I create an image object like this

```
var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');
```

But this is an image object and not a file object which will not allow me to get some file proprieties like `oImage.size` and `oImage.type`. 
The original code is this

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" />
```

And the javascript code

```
function fileSelectHandler() {
   var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];
   ...
}
```

Now I have a function which the callback is a Facebook image URL, and I want it to work just like if I had uploaded the image from my computer, because this input type file gets submited to server.

```
var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');
oImage.src = photo.source;
```

Where `photo.source` is my URL.

So my question is: How to convert a URL to a file type using javascript/ajax? I need to put that type into a file input as well because this is a form that is going to be submited. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to create a local file on someone's remote computer using javascript?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_area_shape

Comment: hob, this is not what i want

Comment: Dory, now I understand what I asked means. The fact is that, from a URL, I need, somehow, to have a $_FILES variable with it's conents to a upload.php file. I have server side access.

Comment: maybe you need imageObject.src=URL

Comment: this might be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: I edited the article with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the URL to your server, then you can download the remote image with PHP and manipulat it.

Hint code:

```
if(isset($_POST['image_url'])){
    //Make sure to validate $_POST['image_url'] before using it
    $image = file_get_contents($_POST['image_url']);
} else {
    $image = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
}
```

I usually use JQuery,
[JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/) sample ajax post:

```
$.post('server.php', {image_url:photo.source}, function(data){
  //do stuff on server response
});
```

Comment: How do I post a file to server from a URL? Is that possible to do that using AJAX? (I really don't want the page to reload)